# How best to update this tree?

Tags: clojure

I've got the following tree:

```
{:start_date "2014-12-07"
  :data {
    :people [
      {:id 1
       :projects [{:id 1} {:id 2}]}
      {:id 2
       :projects [{:id 1} {:id 3}]}
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to update the `people` and `projects` subtrees by adding a `:name` key-value pair.
Assuming I have these maps to perform the lookup:

```
(def people {1 "Susan" 2 "John")
(def projects {1 "Foo" 2 "Bar" 3 "Qux")
```

How could I update the original tree so that I end up with the following?

```
{:start_date "2014-12-07"
  :data {
    :people [
      {:id 1
       :name "Susan"
       :projects [{:id 1 :name "Foo"} {:id 2 :name "Bar"}]}
      {:id 2
       :name "John"
       :projects [{:id 1 :name "Foo"} {:id 3 :name "Qux"}]}
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple combinations of `assoc-in`, `update-in`, `get-in` and `map` calls, but haven't been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used letfn to break down the update into easier to understand units.

```
user> (def tree {:start_date "2014-12-07"
                 :data {:people [{:id 1
                                  :projects [{:id 1} {:id 2}]}
                                 {:id 2
                                  :projects [{:id 1} {:id 3}]}]}})
#'user/tree
user> (def people {1 "Susan" 2 "John"})
#'user/people
user> (def projects {1 "Foo" 2 "Bar" 3 "Qux"})
#'user/projects
user> 
(defn integrate-tree
  [tree people projects]
  ;; letfn is like let, but it creates fn, and allows forward references
  (letfn [(update-person [person]
             ;; -> is the "thread first" macro, the result of each expression
             ;; becomes the first arg to the next
             (-> person
                 (assoc :name (people (:id person)))
                 (update-in [:projects] update-projects)))
          (update-projects [all-projects]
            (mapv
             #(assoc % :name (projects (:id %)))
             all-projects))]
    (update-in tree [:data :people] #(mapv update-person %))))
#'user/integrate-tree
user> (pprint (integrate-tree tree people projects))
{:start_date "2014-12-07",
 :data
 {:people
  [{:projects [{:name "Foo", :id 1} {:name "Bar", :id 2}],
    :name "Susan",
    :id 1}
   {:projects [{:name "Foo", :id 1} {:name "Qux", :id 3}],
    :name "John",
    :id 2}]}}
nil
```

Comment: Thank you. Besides solving my problem, this brought `letfn` to my attention :)

Comment: I don't understand what passing `(projects (:id %))` as the value to the `assoc` lambda does. Isn't `projects` a map? How can it be used as a function in this case?

Comment: Oh, I just realized that `(projects (:id %))` is shorthand for `(get projects (:id %))`.

Comment: One more question - why use `mapv` when `map` seems to have the same effect?

Comment: mapv keeps the type as vector (and is strict). I don't think laziness gains much here

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if entirely the best approach:

```
(defn update-names
  [tree people projects]
  (reduce
   (fn [t [id name]]
     (let [person-idx (ffirst (filter #(= (:id (second %)) id)
                                      (map-indexed vector (:people (:data t)))))
           temp (assoc-in t [:data :people person-idx :name] name)]
       (reduce
        (fn [t [id name]]
          (let [project-idx (ffirst (filter #(= (:id (second %)) id)
                                            (map-indexed vector (get-in t [:data :people person-idx :projects]))))]
            (if project-idx
              (assoc-in t [:data :people person-idx :projects project-idx :name] name)
              t)))
        temp
        projects)))
   tree
   people))
```

Just call it with your parameters:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint (update-names tree people projects))
{:start_date "2014-12-07",
 :data
 {:people
  [{:projects [{:name "Foo", :id 1} {:name "Bar", :id 2}],
   :name "Susan",
   :id 1}
   {:projects [{:name "Foo", :id 1} {:name "Qux", :id 3}],
    :name "John",
    :id 2}]}}
```

With nested reduces

1. Reduce over the people to update corresponding names
2. For each people, reduce over projects to update corresponding names

The noisesmith solution looks better since doesn't need to find person index or project index for each step.

Naturally you tried to `assoc-in` or `update-in` but the problem lies in your tree structure, since the key path to update John name is `[:data :people 1 :name]`, so your `assoc-in` code would look like:

```
(assoc-in tree [:data :people 1 :name] "John")
```

But you need to find John's index in the people vector before you can update it, same things happens with projects inside.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using noisesmith's solution, but your explanation of the index issue was helpful.